# Route53 set latency record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I have following problem. I have set up a domain using AWS (bought from them)
I have two lambdas deployed in two different regions and I want to route traffic to them based on latency

I have setup certificates in both regions (us-west-2 and eu-central-1

Domain is alexandruluca.me.uk and certificates are registered for subdomain keyvalue.alexandruluca.me.uk (I'm doing this for a POC)

In my hosted zone under Route53 I have following

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

The Value/Route traffic to is set to the api gateway of each lambda
If I access the lambda directly via the API gateway, it works just fine.

If I try to access it via https://keyvalue.alexandruluca.me.uk, then I just get

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

By the way, I'm trying to set this up based on https://github.com/alexdebrie/serverless-multi-region

It's a multi region deployment with serverless

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value should not include the protocol (HTTPS) or any specific path.

DNS will map to a resolvable domain name for the CNAME value, you would instead want to create a [custom domain name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) in your API Gateway if you want to resolve to it.

This will give you an execute-api domain that you can then enter as the value, ensure you create it as a Regional endpoint for this.

Comment: I have updated it so that it doesn't include the protocol. Example for the eu-central-1 region
(XXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev)
I still have the same problem, I have uploaded a new screenshot

Comment: It would need to be `XXX.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` with the path

Comment: Just did that change before you answered, didn't work immediately. I checked again after your post and not it works. Big thanks!
It's first time I ever configure route53